# mysql join two tables likes and posts

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

Here is my **php/MySQL** task:

I have a table `POSTS` that contains `num` field that is the primary key and other information fields about the post (`author`, `title`, etc.). I also have a table `LIKE` that contains a `userId` field that is the primary key and a field `POST` that corresponds to the `num` field in `posts`. Given a specific `userID`, I need to get all of the rows from the `POSTS` table that the userId 'likes'.

#### Table 1 - posts

-num 
-author 
-title

#### Table 2 - likes

-userId 
-postId

This is all in **php** so my first idea was to get all of the rows from the `LIKES` table where the `userId` matches the one given and store those rows in an array. Then I would iterate through the array and for each row I would search get the row of the `POSTS` table `where postId=POSTS.num`. However, this seems like it would be rather slow, especially since each iteration through the array would be a separate mysql query.

I am assuming there is a faster way. Would it be to use a temporary table or is there a better way to join the tables? I have to assume that both tables contain many rows. I am a mysql novice so if there is a better solution please explain why it is better. Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
  `posts`.*
FROM
  `likes`
INNER JOIN
  `posts` ON
  `posts`.num = `likes`.postId
WHERE
  `likes`.Userid = {insert user id here}
```

Depending on your schema  (not sure if each record in 'likes' has to be unique, you may want to use the `DISTINCT` keyword on your select to filter out duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT poli.* FROM (
SELECT po.* FROM posts po 
JOIN likes li
ON li.postId = po.num
WHERE li.userId = '$yourGivenUserId'
) AS poli
```

$yourGivenUserId is the given userId.